# Installing Jenkins plugins via API?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install plugins in jenkins, with the help of jenkins remote access API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765728/how-to-install-plugins-in-jenkins-with-the-help-of-jenkins-remote-access-api)

Is there a Jenkins API call which enables remote plugin installation?

The documentation implies that possibility, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I'm trying to automatically install several plugins on newly spun up Jenkins instances.

Comment: Hi.. Can I check where in the documentation you found this implication ?