# Jenkins plugin upgrade

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I have a large fleet of Jenkins instances running in a cluster, all having the LDAP plugin version 1.6 (Jenkins version 1.611). I want to fleet-upgrade the LDAP plugin version to 1.7 (to incorporate environment variables in my plugin configuration). How do I achieve this without manually uploading 1.7 version through UI for each Jenkins instance?

I tried writing a script which basically performs these operations for each Jenkins instance:

1. Replace the existing .jpi/.hpi file in $JENKINS_HOME/plugins for ldap plugin with the correct .hpi file (of the 1.7 version)
2. Edit config.xml under $JENKINS_HOME which has the version number
3. Safe restart Jenkins

It works fine till step 2 but as soon as I perform safe restart, Jenkins magically puts in the original .jpi/.hpi file (the 1.6 version file) back inside $JENKINS_HOME/plugins. Jenkins instance has the 1.6 plugin version again in the UI. Is there a better way to perform fleet plugin upgrades in general? I want to mention that I want the 1.7 plugin version, not the latest

How do I fix this? I even tried using curl (mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20848745/1746529) but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Got a working answer on Google groups.

"As you are on 1.x create an empty  ldap.jpi.pinned file as a sibling and that marker will instruct Jenkins not to replace with the bundled plugin."

Came across the documentation for it as well - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pinned+Plugins