# How to add plugins to jenkins programmatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was trying to find a method to add plugins to Jenkins programmatically and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765728/how-to-install-plugins-in-jenkins-with-the-help-of-jenkins-remote-access-api/20848745#20848745) answer useful. It shows a method using the following curl command and restarting Jenkins after that.

```
curl -X POST -d '<jenkins><install plugin="plugin-name@version" /></jenkins>' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins
```

It worked successfully for many plugins, but it failed for some plugins like Pipeline and Amazon EC2. Below is the command I used to install Pipeline plugin.

```
curl -X POST -d '<jenkins><install plugin="Pipeline@2.6" /></jenkins>' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you need Declarative pipeline plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `plugin-id` in request.

You can find your plugin on https://plugins.jenkins.io and get `plugin-id` from description.

For example Declarative pipeline plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-definition) has id  `pipeline-model-definition`

```
Pipeline: Declarative1.3.9
Minimum Jenkins requirement: 2.150.1
ID: pipeline-model-definition
```