# Jenkins plugins downloaded in windows OS, the same can be use in MAC OS?

Tags: macos, jenkins

I am trying to install jenkins plugins offline and it getting failed. It showing the following error

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out.

Jenkins plugins downloaded from windows OS and the same plugins installed on MACOS as well. it will work or not. Please let me know. plugins is different for each OS?

Comment: Yes works fine; it's a jar.

Answer (score 0):

The plugins are in .jar format. They are not dependent on the OS running your Jenkins server.

To install the plugins manually you should use the UI: Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins >  Advanced > Upload Plugin.

[image]

This will expand the jars in the plugins folder and bring it's dependencies also.

You can also install them through the api as seen [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765728/how-to-install-plugins-in-jenkins-with-the-help-of-jenkins-remote-access-api)

**About plugins**: they have lots of transitive dependencies and sometimes, a plugin upgrade can break the functionalities in your jobs/pipelines. A good practice is to backup the home folder or snapshot the VM before doing any plugins upgrades / installs.

The dependencies tree is why you cannot just copy one plugin folder from another folder without bringing all it's dependencies with it.