# can we install jenkins plugin using nexus as proxy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus, nexus3

I want to install a specific version of jenkins plugin using nexus as a proxy. Is it possible to install from the jenkins UI. If possible, can someone help?

Comment: When pulling a plugin, jenkins also pulls the dependencies . You could store them in jenkins and use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765728/how-to-install-plugins-in-jenkins-with-the-help-of-jenkins-remote-access-api

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.